# Spring Integration order of Spring Integration Events

Tags: events, tcp, spring-integration

I'm dealing with Spring Integration Events and need to ensure proper order of event calls. I have two listeners. One is called TerminalErrorListener and catches TcpConnectionExceptionEvent and TcpDeserializationExceptionEvent. Second is called TerminalDisconnectEventListener and catches TcpConnectionCloseEvent.

In my case I use NIO and manually extended TcpNioConnection with my class which contains one extra field. This field is called Originator and carries information about what caused TcpConnectionCloseEvent and here comes my question.

I define the originator inside TerminalErrorListener and need to ensure that TerminalDisconnectEventListener is called after the TerminalErrorListener.

How can I generally ensure (probably I can guarantee that close event is called after the error) that this will happen? Is there any priority mode or default flow model which can be seen in some kind of diagram? I mean when are specific events called and what is the general sequence of all events.

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

With NIO, there is no guarantee that you will get the deserialization failure event before the connection close event.